# CS1646 Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controller

tables in my EntityFramework model are events, eventtypes, subevents, subeventtypes

using the MVC5 builders (right click on controllers, add, add controller) I created controllers and views for the last three tables without issue however when I create the controller and views for the events entity I produce the following errors
Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @
'EventType' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

the code that was generated in the event controller is 
  {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

```
    // GET: Events
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var events = db.Events.Include(@ => @.EventType); ERROR HERE
        return View(events.ToList());
    }
```

any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated
TIA

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue when using the "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework" template.

```
var @group = await _context.Groups
            .Include(@ => @.Company)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.GroupId == id);
```

My workaround was simple to replace the @ symbol with another character i.e. g

```
var @group = await _context.Groups
            .Include(g => g.Company)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.GroupId == id);
```